# Is there a way to query sub columns and header columns in an APEX Report

Tags: oracle, report, apex

[Example of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFuhW.png)
I was tasked to create a query that does the same actions as an APEX report, a control break, and 2 pivots, one as a header of sub columns and the sub columns.

The end result would be something like this:

```
         |       GR       | BG | UK |   USA   |
-----------------------------------------------
category | 70A | 70B | 68 | BG | UK | KY | OR |
-----------------------------------------------
  Cat1   |     |     |    |    |    |    |    |
-----------------------------------------------
  Cat2   |     |     |    |    |    |    |    |
-----------------------------------------------
  etc.   |     |     |    |    |    |    |    |
```

With control brakes of major categories. If there is a way to do this with a query that would be amazing. Else I will just modify the query and use the Report Actions.

I've made a screenshot of the report example just in case the actual example isn't showing correctly. (Up top)

Thanks in advance!